# where can I find a good source to study robotics kinematics and trajectory planning relative to robotic arm manipulator?

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, trajectory

I am a student, and I have to study for a Robotics exam which consistes mainly in kinematics for a robotic manipulator and trajectory planning also for a robotic manipulator.

In the part relative to kinematics, I have found many sources to study, but for the part relative to trajectory planning I cannot find a complete explanation that allow me to understand deeply the concept.

where can I find a good source to study robotics kinematics and most of all trajectory planning relative to robotics arm manipulator?

I don't know if this is the right place to ask for this, so if it is not in topic with the Robotics exchange policy please tell me and i will delete the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my main source, take a look at this book :

1. Craig, John. J. (2005). Introduction to Robotic : Mechanics and
   Control. Pearson Education Inc.
2. Corke, Peter P. (2017). Robotics, Vision and Control. Springer.
3. Siciliano, B. (2009). Robotic Modelling, Planning and Contol.
   Springer.
4. Paul, P.R. (1981). Robot Manipulator : Mathematics, Programming, and
   Control. MIT.

Comment: I would also recommend the following, which I'm currently using to teach a course on the topic: "Modern Robotics: Mechanics, Planning, and Control" by Lynch and Park. See http://modernrobotics.org for details and a Coursera course as well.

Comment: Also you can take a look at "Trajectory Planning for Automatic Machines and Robots. Springer" by Luigi Biagiotti, Claudio Melchiorri. It has a lot of information about trajectory planning